# Deleting usernames and not via password in a text file

Tags: python, passwords, combinations

```
Guest = {}
with open('LogIn.txt') as f:
    credentials = [x.strip().split(':') for x in f.readlines()]
    for username,password in credentials:
        Guest[username] = password
def DelUser():
    DB = open('LogIn.txt',"r+")
    username = DB.read()
    delete = raw_input("Input username to delete: ")
    if delete in username:
        <insert code to remove line containing username:password combination>
```

So, I have a LogIn.txt file with the following username:password combinations:

```
chris:test
char:coal
yeah:men
test:test
harhar:lololol
```

I want to delete the username:password combination that I want to in the object "delete"
But the problem is, if I use the

```
if delete in username:
```

argument, it'll have to consider the password as well. and example, what if I have two accounts with the same password? Or like the one above. What path can I take for this one? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: This isn't a good choice. Think to memorize password in encrypted way or in a DB with right permissions.

Comment: how do I do that? I'm sorry, I have just been in Python for less than 6 months, and have limited knowledge too.

Comment: This isn't a python issue but a security. Read somethin about. On G' you can find everything

Comment: As an aside, the convention for python is that only classes get names `LikeThis`. Methods, functions, and variables get names `like_this` (and constants `LIKE_THIS`) - see [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your current DelUser function, you can read the file, remove the line that start with the user to delete, and write a new one:

```
def DelUser():

    # read the current files, and get one line per user/password
    with open('LogIn.txt',"r+") as fd:
        lines = fd.readlines()

    # ask the user which one he want to delete
    delete = raw_input("Input username to delete: ")

    # filter the lines without the line starting by the "user:"
    lines = [x for x in lines if not x.startswith('%s:' % delete)]

    # write the final file
    with open('LogIn.txt', 'w') as fd:
        fd.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this. care to explain?

Comment: Oh! I see, I see, I get this one now :) thanks :) this shortens my code more. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if delete in Guest:
```

to test if `delete` is a key in `Guest`. Since the keys of `Guest` represent  usernames, `if delete in Guest` tests if `delete` is a username.

---

You could use the [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) module to rewrite the file "inplace":

```
import fileinput
import sys

def DelUser(Guest):
    delete = raw_input("Input username to delete: ")
    for line in fileinput.input(['LogIn.txt'], inplace = True, backup = '.bak'):
        if delete not in Guest:
            sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: but then I want to remove the username from the text file and not only in the Guest dict. any suggestions?